# Boot from docker volume

Tags: docker, linux-from-scratch

I'm trying to build Linux From Scratch in docker. It expects a mounted volume on which it'll build a system you can boot from, so my plan was to attach a docker volume to a normal docker ubuntu container to build the LFS system and stuff it into the volume, then boot another docker container from said volume.

It says no to the latter:

```
docker: Error response from daemon: invalid mount config for type "volume": invalid specification: destination can't be '/'.
```

That makes sense considering I was trying to boot a ubuntu docker image, but how am I to achieve this?

Perhaps I should be content with a docker image that has a tiny boot partition of its own which then mounts the LFS system volume to find all the /usr stuff. I guess LFS will make that easy, but I'm not sure how to make that docker image. How does one start a docker image from nothing and put grub, vmlinuz, etc into it?

Comment: To clarify, what do you mean by "boot a Docker image"?  A Docker image is basically just a sandboxed process, it's not a VM that can be booted.  (Though I may be missing something here...)

Comment: Well I suppose I mean run a container based on the image. Or perhaps there's some better terminology.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question let me first start with booting host OS process - it starts with; BIOS - grub - vmlinuz - os - filesystem - system services - user services; Now coming to docker  - It is sandbox and make use of the existing running kernel thus the booting of docker process is; mount filesystem - system services - user services; The volumes are mounted with the base filesystem like ext2, ext3, etc., Since docker is sandbox we can bring more than 1000 dockers in seconds